# Do all functors $\mathcal{Cat}\to\mathcal{Cat}$ preserve adjunctions?

Tags: category-theory

Let's say we have an adjunction $f\dashv g$ between functors $f:\mathscr C\to\mathscr D$ and $g:\mathscr D\to\mathscr C$. Now let $H:\mathcal{Cat}\to\mathcal{Cat}$ be a functor. Is it then true that $Hf\dashv Hg$ as well?

My intuition says no, but I cannot seem to cook up a counterexample.

Comment: The easiest counterexample: take each category to its opposite.

Comment: @ZhenLin Fair enough, thanks. What if we just require either $Hf\dashv Hg$ or $Hg\dashv Hf$? (this is of interest because both will imply that $BH\mathscr C\simeq BH\mathscr D$, where $B:\mathcal{Cat}\to\mathcal{Top}$ is the classifying space functor.)

Comment: What you really need is a 2-functor.

Comment: Ah right, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Zhen says, what you really want is a [2-functor](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-functor). Adjunctions involve natural transformations, so they're really a 2-categorical notion, and in fact they not only make sense in any 2-category, but their definition is purely 2-categorically equational (using the unit-counit definition), hence adjunctions in any 2-category are preserved by 2-functors.

Examples of 2-functors $\text{Cat} \to \text{Cat}$ include the 2-functor $C \mapsto [J, C]$ given by sending a category $C$ to the functor category $[J, C]$ (as long as all size issues are taken care of). Hence an adjunction between two categories $C, D$ induces, "pointwise," an adjunction between functor categories $[J, C], [J, D]$.